# Androdi AdMob native ad AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I was using the admob banner and it works fine.
I have  migrated to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1`
and Firebase, I have the new google_services.json

I have created a new native ad unit and I waited 24h.

I'm trying to load the add in the RecyclerView.Adapter
I tried loading the add in ViewHolder initialisation and also in onBindViewHolder, no change.
In the setAdListener I receive onAdLoaded(), but still this error:

`E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)`

I tried with loading it with test device, and I got this:

```
 D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
 I/Ads: Starting ad request.

                                                                    --------- beginning of system
 W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
 W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 1
```